# Cisco 877 - trouble with DNS

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns

I have and am attempting to set up a Cisco 877W-G-A-K9 to use on my home network.  I have managed to connect it to the internet; from the command line of the 877, I can ping domain names and get a response eg:

```
    Cisco877#ping outlook.msexchangehosted.com
    Translating "outlook.msexchangehosted.com"...domain server (208.67.222.222) [OK]

    Type escape sequence to abort.
    Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 62.75.254.190, timeout is 2 seconds:
    !!!!!
    Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 336/336/340 ms</code>
```

So DNS from within the router is working.

However, when my laptop connects, I cannot ping from the command line, getting the immediate response of

```
    Ping request could not find host google.com Please check the name and try again.
```

but nslookup from the same command line produces :

```
    C:\Windows\System32>nslookup google.com
    Server:  resolver1.opendns.com
    Address:  208.67.222.222

    Non-authoritative answer:
    Name:    google.com
    Addresses:  2404:6800:4006:807::200e
              172.217.25.174
```

So DNS works there .... but I still cannot access the web.  Now here is the strange thing, an iPhone 6, connecting wirelessly to the router has full internet access, can browse, message, email - everything; it's only my laptop that is unable browse ... until I plug back into my Netgear DGN200v3 then I am back online again, so I don't think it is a computer hardware problem.

I searched and found numerous people had posted similar issues but sadly the resolutions posted I have already instituted! i.e. adding name servers, adding a list of dns servers to my DHCP pool etc etc.

I then found a post that suggested that if you had DNS resolver issues, it was to do with your MTUs .... I did a show ip int and noted the following from it:

```
    Dialer 0 MTU - 1492
    NVI 0 MTU - 1514
    BVI 1 MTU - 1500 ( with ip tcp adjust-mss 1452 set)
```

I tried changing adjust-mss in BVI 1 to the maximum 1460 and MTU in Dialer 0 to 1500.  No, same problem.

The last two outputs may mean something - I truly don't know for I lack the knowledge or experience to interpret them, but I did a show ip cef from the Router:

```
    Cisco877#show ip cef
    Prefix             Next Hop      Interface
    0.0.0.0/0          attached      Dialer0
    0.0.0.0/32         receive
    144.138.131.0/24   attached      Dialer0
    144.138.131.0/32   receive
    144.138.131.214/32 receive
    144.138.131.255/32 receive
    155.143.128.142/32 attached      Dialer0
    192.168.0.0/24     attached      BVI1
    192.168.0.0/32     receive
    192.168.0.1/32     receive
    192.168.0.2/32     192.168.0.2   BVI1
    192.168.0.3/32     192.168.0.3   BVI1
    192.168.0.16/32    192.168.0.16  BVI1
    192.168.0.17/32    192.168.0.17  BVI1
    192.168.0.20/32    192.168.0.20  BVI1
    192.168.0.255/32   receive
    224.0.0.0/4        drop
    224.0.0.0/24       receive
    255.255.255.255/32 receive
```

And then a show ip dns statistics :

```
    Cisco877#show ip dns statistics
    DNS requests received = 25 ( 24 + 1 )
    DNS requests dropped = 0 ( 0 + 0 )
    DNS responses replied = 0 ( 0 + 0 )

    Forwarder queue statistics:
    Current size = 0
    Maximum size = 6
    Drops = 0

    Director queue statistics:
    Current size = 0
    Maximum size = 0
    Drops = 0
```

So ... has anybody else come across this issue before? and how was it resolved? I suspect that the MTU may be mismatched or similar, but don't really know where to start changing to resolve it.  MTU in my Dialer is set to 1492, and in my bridge group, BVI1, ip tcp adjust-mss is set to 1452

Answer (score 0):

And for all those Cisco fans ... I have answered my own question (again!! getting to be a bit of a habit, this)

The relevant issues were:

in Dialer0:
set MTU to 1460
set ip nat enable
set ppp tcp adjust-mss to 1420

in BVI1
set ip nat enable
set ppp tcp adjust-mss to 1420